# Folland Tonelli Theorem why is monotone convergence needed in this case?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, measure-theory

In the following proof by Folland, why is it true that "The monotone convergence theorem implies, first that the corresponding $g_n$ and $h_n$ increase to $g$ and $ h$"? Isn't this a consequence of the existance of simple functions which increase to $f$ as in theorem 2.10? Why is the Monotone Convergence theorem needed to justify this claim?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define for each $x\in X$, $g(x):=\int_Yf(x,y)\,d\nu(y)$ and $g_n(x):=\int_Yf_n(x,y)\,d\nu(y)$. Since $f_{n}\leq f_{n+1}$ pointwise, we have
\begin{align}
g_n(x)=\int_Yf_n(x,y)\,d\nu(y)\leq \int_Yf_{n+1}(x,y)\,d\nu(y)=g_{n+1}(x)
\end{align}
This shows $g_1\leq g_2\leq \dots$. We still have to show $g$ is the pointwise limit of $g_n$; this follows by MCT because
\begin{align}
g(x)&:=\int_Yf(x,y)\,d\nu(y)\\
&=\int_Y\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x,y)\,d\nu(y)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Yf_n(x,y)\,d\nu(y)\tag{$*$}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(x),
\end{align}
where the interchange of limits and integrals is justified by applying monotone convergence to the functions $f_n(x,\cdot )$ on $Y$, which increase to $f(x,\cdot)$.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. I have one more question. Why is it that $\lim \int g_n d\mu =\lim \int f_n d(\mu \times v)$?

Comment: @SamKirkiles can you write out fully what $\int g_nd\mu$ is

Comment: Sure it would be $\int \int f_n(x,y) d v (y) d \mu (x)$ @peek-a-boo

Comment: @SamKirkiles you're missing the subscript $n$. Now look at the very first sentence of the proof.

Comment: I don't quite see is it because it reduces to theorem 2.36? The aspect that is tripping me up is how we are getting the $\mu \times v$ @peek-a-boo

Comment: @SamKirkiles explain to me in a mathematical statement what the first sentence of Folland is saying.

Comment: Ah I think I see since $f$ is a simple function, then the problem reduces to Theorem 2.36 so we should have that $\int f_n d( \mu \times v)=\int \int f_n(x,y)dv(y)d \mu(x)$. I think I wasn't seeing why the problem was reduced to 2.36 but the function is assumed to be a characteristic function, we have that $\int f d (\mu \times v) = \mu \times v (E)$ and from there linearity allows it to work for simple functions.

Comment: @Sam Kirkiles Yes exactly